# Inapp Billing in android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have used demo of **Inappbilling** from developer site

but i have one question in that i don't have any idea about that
If once user install the app and purchase some items using in app billing
after some time he uninstall the app and again install app 
At that time does all previous purchased items will be shown?
Is there any service for that give data about purchased items of particular user?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am fine and u? Yes I am here..

Comment: Hello, Have u any code of GPS which is used to get current location quickly.??? Please give me the code fastly... Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

I found this:

> RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS This request retrieves a user's transaction
>   status for managed purchases. You should send this request only when
>   you need to retrieve a user's transaction status, which is usually
>   only when your application is **reinstalled** or installed for the
>   first time on a device.